# php for-loop array rewriting performance

Tags: php, arrays, drupal, drupal-7

I have written a simple php script running within drupal. It imports json from a different server and converts it to a multidimensional array. when I added a for-loop which rewrites the array a bit, the loading time increased from 1 second to 5 seconds. Am I doing something wrong here?

part of original "fast" code:

```
public function give_nausys_request_rew_array()  {
            $this->jsonarray = drupal_json_decode($this->give_nausys_request());
            $this->jsonarray = $this->jsonarray[reservations];

            return $this->jsonarray;

    }
```

part of "slow" code:

```
public function give_nausys_request_rew_array()  {
            $this->jsonarray = drupal_json_decode($this->give_nausys_request());
            $this->jsonarray = $this->jsonarray[reservations];
            $this->arraycount = count($this->jsonarray)-1;

            for ($i = 0; $i <= $this->arraycount; $i++) {
                    $this->jsonarray[$i][GUID] = $this->jsonarray[$i][yachtId].'-'.$this->jsonarray[$i][periodFrom].'-'.$this->jsonarray[$i][periodTo];

                }

            return $this->jsonarray;

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

i don't know the average size of your array, but maybe the count function in php needs to loop through your array to perform the counting. So maybe you are actually looping through your array two times. Try maybe using foreach, and the php will handle loop for you.